# Mysql IN - All values are compulsary and not 'OR'

Tags: mysql

I have this part of a query

```
SELECT * FROM conference WHERE active='1' AND conference_feature_id IN (8,9)
```

Now this query, loads the rows that are either set to 8 **OR** 9.

Is there a way how can use the IN function (with the commas if possible) to load the rows that have 8 **AND** 9 only.

So the rows which don`t have them both would not show

I could do a simple WHERE statement, but I am in desperate need to use the IN function if possible

RESULTS EXPLAINED HERE[image]

Comment: The way that the `IN` operator works is it compares the value of the left side (in this case `conference_feature_id`) to the set of values in the right side (in this case `8,9`), so there is never a case where the value will equal both 8 and 9.  Maybe you should show your use case to help us understand better?

Comment: use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html) or use [subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html)

Comment: so you want conference_feature_id to have both value 8 and 9 at the same time? that seems impossible to me

Comment: `field IN (8,9)` is expanded as `(field = 8 OR field = 9)`, so there's no way a given field can have two states at the same time. And besides  a field or variable can have only one value at a time

Comment: check out my image... i did a group concat to show you that there is 2 values for each conference room as this is a many to many table... so for example in this example conference_room_id 3 should not be there.... You think the UNION is best as my query is more complex then just a simple select ( I pasted only a part of it)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
select * from conference where active='1' and 9 in conference_feature and 8 in conf
```

Comment: Hi MRR, are you sure this accepted answer is running? I tried this same code construct, but it has syntax error http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/3b857/7

Answer (score 1):

That should work:

```
SELECT * FROM myTbl as myTbl1 WHERE active='1' AND conference_feature_id = 8
JOIN
SELECT * FROM myTbl as myTbl2 WHERE active='1' AND conference_feature_id = 9
ON myTbl1.id = myTbl2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

TRY

```
SELECT * FROM conference WHERE active='1' AND conference_feature_id = 8
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM conference WHERE active='1' AND conference_feature_id = 9
```

Comment: How would this return results different from the original `IN`?

Comment: check out my image... i did a group concat to show you that there is 2 values for each conference room as this is a many to many table... so for example in this example conference_room_id 3 should not be there.... You think the UNION is best as my query is more complex then just a simple select ( I pasted only a part of it)..

Comment: @MRR your question has layers, you didnt write complete question in once, how do we understand then.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you really want is to load all active conference (grouped on primary key) that contains exactly two conference features only: 8 AND 9

```
SELECT * 
FROM conference 
WHERE conference_id IN
(
   SELECT conference_id 
   FROM conference 
   GROUP BY conference_id
   HAVING SUM(conference_feature_id IN (8,9)) = 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I the best the best query I found is

```
SELECT * FROM conference WHERE active='1' AND 
conference_feature_id = '8' AND 
conference_feature_id ='9'
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following works, but I'm sure someone with better understanding of `SET` types and bit operators in SQL could give a cleaner version:

```
SELECT * FROM conference WHERE 
  active='1' 
  AND 
  FIND_IN_SET(8, conference_feature_id) > 0 
  AND
  FIND_IN_SET(9, conference_feature_id) > 0
```